# Find the projection of V in the direction of vector W

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projection-matrices

v = [2,3] and w = [0,1]

projw(v) = w*v/||w||^2 = 3[0,1]=[0,3]

Did I do the right step?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is correct but the dot product part is not legible. The $\mathbf {vector}$ projection of $v$ in the direction of $w$ should be written as $$\frac{(\vec v.\vec w)\vec w}{|w|^2}$$
Just magnitude of component of $\vec v$ along $\vec w$ would lead to omission of $\frac{\vec w}{|w|}$ from the expression.